# Insert line separator in spannablestringbuilder after imagespans (Android)

Tags: android, spannablestring, imagespan

I have a spannablestringbuilder with a number of imagespans in it.  I would like to insert a line separator after the image to ensure that text following it starts on the next line.

I am trying to do this in a loop, but it doesn't insert the line seprator and breaks the spans.

```
ImageSpan[] imageSpans = strBuilder.getSpans(0, strBuilder.length(), ImageSpan.class);
    for (ImageSpan imageSpan : imageSpans) {
        strBuilder = strBuilder.insert(strBuilder.getSpanEnd(imageSpan), System.getProperty("line.separator") );
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was adding new ImageSpans elsewhere in the code and not removing previously added ones.  This led to the inconsistencies, removing old imagespans after adding a new one resolved the issue.