# Add extra line in SpannableStringBuilder getSpans()

Tags: android, url, spannablestring, spannablestringbuilder

I am combining different strings to show in a `TextView`. I am doing this using a `SpannableStringBuilder`, as I need to apply a different color to a few substrings in the string. Now in the combined strings, there are urls which I show in different colors along with some other text. I am doing something like below.

```
Spannable spannedText = (Spannable) Util.getFormattedText(plainText);
SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(spannedText);
URLSpan[] urls = strBuilder.getSpans(0, spannedText.length(), URLSpan.class);
for (URLSpan span : urls)
{
    //apply clicks               
}
```

Output is : `Link1 Link2 some links here.`

I want to show each url on a different line with the rest of the text after the urls.

eg.

```
Link1
Link2
some links here
```

But I am not able to find a solution for this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `\n` does not work?

Comment: @pskink No. The links I want to show are dynamic, so I don't know how many links I am going to receive.

Comment: so what if they are dynamic? i dont see any problem here - just add `\n` after each `URLSpan`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do like what is mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290932/insert-line-separator-in-spannablestringbuilder-after-imagespans-android) answer.

Just use your `UrlSpan` instead of `ImageSpan` like below :-

```
for (URLSpan span : urls)
{
  strBuilder = strBuilder.insert(strBuilder.getSpanEnd(span), System.getProperty("line.separator"));
  //apply clicks     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SpanableString

```
    SpannableString spanUrl1 = new SpannableString("www.google.com");
    spanUrl1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, spanUrl1.length(), 
                       Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
   Spannable spanUrl2 = new SpannableString("www.stackoverflow.com");
   spanUrl2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, spanUrl2.length(), 
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

   TV.setText(TextUtils.concat(spanUrl1, "\n",spanUrl2));
   TV.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where does this code put the links on separate line?

Comment: I am already applying colors to the different sections. My issue is that I need them to be on separate lines

Comment: @user3034944 check my answer i had updated my answer.